# EditText: suppress soft keyboard but allow selection and cursor?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I want to display an `EditText` which will be edited mostly by selecting parts of it and pressing buttons to insert new values.  (The values are long hex strings which I don't want the user to have to type.)  Therefore, I want to suppress the display of the soft keyboard unless the user deliberately calls it up.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373673/suppress-appearance-of-the-soft-keyboard-on-edittext-focus) describes almost exactly the same requirement, but the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373737/1953590) does not work on Android 5.1.  When the input mode is changed to `InputType.TYPE_NULL`, the `EditText` disables *all* editing functionality, not just the soft keyboard.  There's no cursor, no click-drag selection, etc.

Overriding `onCheckIsTextEditor()` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5803257/1953590) behaves the same way.

Is there any way to accomplish this on Android 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was added in API 21:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

According to [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/search/?start=0&query=setShowSoftInputOnFocus&entity=method), this method has been present but hidden since version 4.1.1.  So you can annotate the method that calls it as `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)`, and protect the call itself with `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)`.

Comment: Works great.  When part of the text is selected, a drawer-like view opens from the top of the screen with "select all", "cut", and "paste" buttons.  I can live with that.

Comment: I edited the answer to explain the real reason it works on lower APIs.  It has nothing to do with the support library.